Did Noah have kids at 500 years old?
According to genealogy of Noah’s family history ( Gen 5-6) all of Noah’s forefathers had children before they were 200, this lending to the theory that Noah also had his children according to family tradition by the time he was 200. This would allow time for the boys to grow up and get married several hundred years before Noah began the ark. So then Noah would have 3 strong young men and Four healthy women to help build the ark with him. This seems logical. The original wording does not say that his wife bore children when he was five hundred, but that at five hundred, he already had grown children. Critical thinking support this scenario, because Noah would have had small children to care for and grow up and marry all the while he was building the ark… this doesn’t seem to fit the narrative very well.

Gen 5:32 - After Noah was 500 years old, he became the father of Shem,
Ham, and Japheth.


There are several flaws in the OP's logic, viz:

That Noah's children consisted only of Shem, Ham and Japheth.  It is quite possible that Noah had many more children, but only the three recorded were included on the Ark.
That Noah raised Children entirely by himself.  Indeed, families in that time were raised by more than just the parents.
That Shem Ham and Japheth were the only people who assisted Noah in constructing the Ark.  Indeed, Noah's extended family may well have assisted as well as earlier children but some of them died before the Ark was completed or apostatized before the ark was completed.

What are the Biblical facts?

Gen 7:6 - Noah was 600 years old when the flood came on the earth
Gen 11:10 - two years after the flood, Shem was 100 years old.  Therefore, Shem was born to Noah at the age of 502.
Gen 6:3 - Noah spent 120 years building the Ark and preparing for the flood.  Therefore, he started this process at the age of 480.  It is entirely possible, even highly probable, that at that time Noah had other children.

